# Date product custom field usage in Woocommerce WC_Product_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-fields

I have a woocommerce site that I am currently adding functionality to, I have products which have expiry dates and would like to display all products which have an expiry date of today on a particular page. In addition to this I would also like to have all products which have an expiry date of tomorrow displayed on another page.

I found the following documentation online: [Adding Custom Parameter Support](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query#adding-custom-parameter-support)

I have added this to my site via the snippets plugin and modified it for my expiry date attribute

```
/** * Handle a custom 'expirydate' query var to get products with the 'expirydate' meta.
 * @param array $query - Args for WP_Query.
 * @param array $query_vars - Query vars from WC_Product_Query.
 * @return array modified $query
 */

function handle_custom_query_var( $query, $query_vars ) {
if ( ! empty( $query_vars['expirydate'] ) ) {
    $query['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key' => 'expirydate',
        'value' => esc_attr( $query_vars['expirydate'] ),
    );
}

return $query;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'handle_custom_query_var', 10, 2 );
```

I then have another snippet added which is to create the function to call for the products which have the expiry date of today and to this I've added a shortcode to easily call this on my site on the pages I want it to be displayed.

```
// Display products with expiry date today

function expiry_Date_Today()
{
$todaysdate = date(d/m/Y);

$products = wc_get_products( array( 'expirydate' => 'todaysdate' ) );
}
add_shortcode( 'expirydatetoday', 'expiry_Date_Today');
```

Now my issue here is that when I use the shortcode on my page I get nothing in return. Just a blank empty space. I assume this is because I need to request the output in a format that would show the products. I would preferably want this to appear as an image, title and the add to cart button similar to what you you would generally see when viewing the contents of a category page.

I have searched online but cannot find this information so could someone point me in the right direction here or if there appears to be something obviously wrong with my code could you assist?

Many thanks,
TMS.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

There are multiple mistakes in your code and your expired date should be always set in `'Y-m-d'` compatible date format instead, to be able to compare dates if required.

Try the following, that will get expired products list from today date:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'handle_custom_query_var', 10, 2 );
function handle_custom_query_var( $query, $query_vars ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['expirydate'] ) ) {
        $query['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key'       => 'expirydate',
            'value'     => esc_attr( $query_vars['expirydate'] ),
            'compare'   => '=',
            'type'    => 'DATE'
        );
    }
    return $query;
}

function get_products_expired_today($atts ) {
    // Extract shortcode attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'date' => date('Y-m-d'), // default date is current date in 'd/m/Y' format
    ), $atts, 'expirydatetoday' ) );

    $products = wc_get_products(  array(
        'status'      => 'publish',
        'limit'       => -1,
        'expirydate'  => $date,
    ) );

    $html = '<ul class="expired-products">';

    // Products loop
    foreach( $products as $product ) {
        $html .= '<li><a href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $product->get_name() . '</a></li>';
    }

    return $html . '</ul>';
}
add_shortcode( 'expirydatetoday', 'get_products_expired_today');
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Now if you want to get all expired products instead of the "today" products, you will need first to change the date format on your `expirydate` custom field value for all products to "YYYY`MM-DD".

You will have to change:

```
'compare'   => '=',
```

to:

```
'compare'   => '<=',
```

It also works.

Comment: I will give this a try today and will get back with the result. I've voted up your answer but as my rep is low it may not show - thank you!

Comment: Hi, so I have tried the first code that you provided and it does populate a list of product names with product links but it is showing all products within our store and not just those that have the expirydate attribute as today (02/02/2021).

Comment: I can confirm I have removed all of the values that were set as d/m/Y format and have renamed them to be in the YYYY-MM-DD format. 

I have also changed the date format to the default Y-m-d in my code within my functions.php file however it is still populating all products on my page. 

I actually only have one product which has the attribute expirydate and the value 2021-02-02 so I assumed it would only show this one product.

Comment: Thank you, I have used the updated code but it is now returning a blank page. I have checked that my attribute slug is correctly named as expirydate and that the value I have entered in is in the correct format 2021-02-02

Comment: @TMS Sorry But I have tested the code and it works without any issue… Check that you have removed all your old code. End.

Comment: No problem, I will have a look around and see if something is wrong which would be preventing it from displaying. Thank you for your assistance.